# NetSuite SuiteScript 2.0 - Attach File Object to Email Being Sent Via SuiteScript

Tags: email, netsuite, email-attachments, suitescript2.0

I am writing a script where I am trying to print a transaction and then email it.  I keep getting the following error.

**"Wrong parameter type: options.attachments is expected as file.File[]."**

I can't tell what is wrong with my code. Here is the snipped of code that is causing the issues.  The email sends just fine if I don't include the attachments parameter. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
var recID = 1213;

var userID = 1478;

var emailSender = 1478;

var emailSubject = "Test Email";

var emailBody = "This is a test.";

var mainRecipient = "test@test.com";

var additionalRecipients = "";

var recPDF = render.transaction({
    entityId: recID,
    printMode: render.PrintMode.PDF,

});

email.send({
    author: author,
    recipients: mainRecipient,
    subject: emailSubject,
    cc: additionalRecipients,
    body: emailBody,
    attachments: [recPDF],
    relatedRecords: {
        transactionId: recID
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Figured out my issue. There was a conflict attachment for some reason with the library file I had attached to the Suitelet running the script.  By removing the library file, it resolved the issue.